# How to preserve already approved app in itunes connect?

Tags: app-store-connect

The first version of our app 1.0.0 was uploaded and approved by Apple and currently, it has a status "Developer Removed From Sale". However this version has severals bugs and some features  are missing, so we decided not to release it, to improve it and release another version.

So, we uploaded another version 1.1.0 after some time, and currently, it has "Pending Developer Release" status. The funny thing is managing guys decided to add yet another features, so we will have to upload the third version.

The question is will the second approved app version (1.1.0) be there after uploading the third version to itunes connect, or will it be deleted? We definitely don't need the first version because there are bugs but it's unable to delete it even if it was not released to app store. But I would prefer to have the second version until the third be approved (just in case).

Answer (score 0):

The current approved version will remain Ready for Sale (wether you choose to put it live on the App Store by making in available in one, some or all countries or not) while the Update is Waiting for Review, In Review, and Processing for the App Store, and will be removed when the Update's status goes to Ready for Sale. (It will also remain should the Update be Rejected.)